# Aggregating raster using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, aggregation

I have a GeoTIFF which is at 30m resolution. I need to downsample it to 250m resolution (using some aggregating function such as mean, mode, sum). My stack is python (rasterio and GDAL bindings)

I can find a way to do this directly using numpy writing some nasty double loops and iterating over the matrices directly but looking for a cleaner way.

Note that the main issue is that 250 is not a multiple of 30 and there will be some overflow. For instance if the aggregating function is the sum the algorithm would be to use:

1. 8 X 8 block which is 240m X 240m in base resolution
2. Chose a partial pixel strip at 10m X 10m to complete the sum to 250m
3. The value for 2. would be area weighted and added to the sum from 1.

Please let me know if I was unclear. Again I can find a brute force way to do it using matrix manipulations but was wondering if there is an elegant way. I am open to using `R` also and read about the `projectRaster` and aggregate methods but they seem to work on integer cut offs also.

In general it may be really cumbersome to do this for an arbitrary resolution say 31.567m or so.

Comment: Perhaps gdalwarp with our favorite resampling method http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html? If the partial pixels make problem oversample to 10 m pixel size first.

Comment: there is no way to calculate the sum?

Comment: Unfortunately, No

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163521)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163521)

Answer (score 8):

I'd use [`gdalwarp`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to resample (downsample in this case) data:

```
gdalwarp -tr 250 250 -r average input_r30.tif output_r250.tif
```

Instead, using the GDAL Python bindings:

```
from osgeo import gdal

inDs = gdal.Open('input_r30.tif')
outDs = gdal.Warp('output_r250.tif', inDs,
                  format = 'GTiff',
                  xRes = 250, yRes = 250,
                  resampleAlg = gdal.GRA_Average)

inDs = None
outDs = None
```

In both examples, I've used the average resampling method, but you can choose it among the supported ones:

```
GRA_NearestNeighbour = 0
GRA_Bilinear = 1
GRA_Cubic = 2
GRA_CubicSpline = 3
GRA_Lanczos = 4
GRA_Average = 5
GRA_Mode = 6
GRA_Gauss = 7
```

Because 250 is not a multiple of 30, the output will have a little bigger spatial extent than the input.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @MikeT, who has opened a [ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7153) in GDAL bug tracker, *"the extra GRA constants will be available for convenience through the SWIG Python bindings in the next [**GDAL 2.2.3 release**](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.2.3-News), soon to be available."* These are the relatively new constants:

```
GRA_Max = 8
GRA_Min = 9
GRA_Med = 10
GRA_Q1 = 11
GRA_Q3 = 12
```

---

**UPDATE:** GDAL 2.2.3 has been released today (2017/11/23):
https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-November/047782.html

Comment: GDAL 2.x brought in a few more `-r resampling method` options, such as `min`, `max`, `med`, `q1`, `q3`; see [details here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Antonio. Few more questions 1) How does it treat partial pixels, in other words if the input resolution is say 35.576m, and the output is 100m, does it combine 3 pixels into 1 or fractional pixels? 2) Also why would be extent be larger? I also notice that it tends to give different pixel size if I don't constrain it using the -tr parameter, why is that, In other words if I dont specify constraints on the output how does it chose the pixel size while warping (say from aea proj to utm )?

Comment: @MikeT Those resampling method options seems to be available only when using `gdalwarp` directly, while the OP was asking about his Python stack.

Comment: @ganeshreddy Don't mention it. 1) The theoretical "fractional pixels" are treated as normal ones, so it should combine 3 pixels into 1, i.e. the minimum number of pixels necessary to avoid loosing information. 2) Some `gdalwarp` options are mutually exclusive. For instance, if you set the output file size you can't force the pixel size and viceversa. For further considerations we should inspect the source code because warping has several options and use cases.

Comment: I see so is that the primary reason for the increased extent? So for instance in our case it will end up chosing 9 X 9 blocks (so 30*9 = 270) and hence gain 20m (270-250) for each averaging? Am I getting this right? Also what do to if we have a custom function not implemented in the standard interpolation?

Comment: @AntonioFalciano the extra resampling methods are available for Python too, [just a bit hidden](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/1f168ebf6bfd8eb64285e6c3dea1c75bec75b6f8/gdal/alg/gdalwarper.h#L50-L64).

Comment: @MikeT Glad to know it, thanks. The newest resampling methods are not shown in [Python GDAL API](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdalconst-module.html#GRA_Average) yet, but they're implemented.

Comment: @AntonioFalciano, what is the difference between GRIORA and GRA resampling?

Comment: @dr_times [GRIORA](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a640ada511cbddeefac67c548e009d5ac) should mean GDAL Raster IO Resample Algorithm, while [GRA](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarper_8h.html#a4775b029869df1f9270ad554c0633843) GDAL Resample Algorithm. The correspondent constants (e.g. `GRIORA.Average` and `GRA.Average`) should have the same value (e.g. 5) and so are equivalent operationally.

Comment: @AntonioFalciano, thanks. Does it mean that resampling in gdal.Warp in the example above is performed on IO operation? Could you please provide an example on how to understand when to use GRIORA and GRA types of interpolation?

Comment: @dr_times No matter what acronym comes before the name of the resampling method, because the algorithms are the same. I could write 5 instead of *.Average and it should work the same, because they are only some integer constants. With or without IO operations. Rigorously, GRA constants should be those of gdal.Warp, even it's not mandatory to use them for the reasons I told you before.

Comment: @AntonioFalciano the extra GRA constants will be available for convenience through the SWIG Python bindings in the next [GDAL 2.2.3 release](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.2.3-News), soon to be available.

Comment: @MikeT +1 Thank you very much for opening a ticket: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7153