# How to downsample a raster using the gdal max method using python?

Tags: python, gdalwarp, resampling

I want to downsample a raster image using the max method that is available in GDAL in python.

In other words I would like to recreate the following bash command in python code:

```
gdalwarp -tr 32 32 -r max input_image.tif resampled_image.tif
```

I have found the following [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262316/aggregating-raster-using-gdal) but for some reason this changes the values in the image to a range between approximately 0 and 2 when I load the created tif file.

How can I resample a raster image in python using the max method?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably passing other resampling algorithm than `max` when using the solution you linked. The code should look like:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

gdal.Warp('resampled_image.tif', 'input_image.tif', xRes=32 yRes=32, resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Max)
```

Another alternative is calling the command from Python using the `subprocess` module:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run('gdalwarp -tr 32 32 -r max input_image.tif resampled_image.tif')
```